# Spring Unit Test Failing Due to Incorrect Return Type

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

This is method called acknowledgement for which I am writing the Unit test.

```
public String acknowledgement(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, NotificationMessage message) throws Exception {

OperatorSubscriber os = (Operator Subscriber) request.getSession().getAttribute("operator");

// check to see if acknowledge selected or acknowledge all

if (message.getBtnClicked().equals("Acknowledge Selected Notifications")) {

// if something was selected

if (message.getSelectedMessages() != null) {

for (int i = 0; i \< message.getSelectedMessages().length; i++) {

// get the notificationID

Long notificationId = new Long(message.getSelectedMessages()\[i\].toString());

if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {

Logger.info("Moving To History, NotificationID = "+ message.getSelectedMessages()\[i\].toString()); }

delegate.acknowledgeNotification(os, notificationId); // acknowledge the notification

} return "redirect:/viewNotifications.do";

} else {

return "redirect:/viewNotifications.do";

go back the notification page

} else if (message.getBtnClicked().equals("Acknowledge All Notifications")) {

// acknowledge all the notifications

if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {

Logger.info("Acknowledge All Notifications selected");

}

delegate.acknowledgeAllNotifications (os, getMaxnotificationid(message.getNotificationIds()));

return "redirect:/viewNotifications.do";

} else

return "redirect:/viewNotifications.do";

}
```

---

and this is the getMaxNotificationsid method

```
public long getMaxnotificationid(String\[\] notificationids) {

if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {

Logger.debug("Notification ID List:\\n");

}

ArrayList list = new ArrayList\<\>(notificationids.length);

for (int i = 0; i \< notificationids.length; i++) {

System.out.println(notificationids\[i\]); list.add(new Long(notificationids\[i\]));

if (logger.isDebugEnabled())

Logger.debug(notificationids\[i\] + ",");

}

long maxnotificationid = ((Long) Collections.max(list)).longValue();

if (logger.isDebugEnabled())

Logger.debug("\\nMax Notification ID = " + maxnotificationid);

return maxnotificationid;

}
```

And this is the Unit test I have written

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.\*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NotificationServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    
    @Mock
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    
    @Mock
    private DaoDelegate delegate;
    
    @Mock
    private HttpSession session;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private NotificationService service;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testAcknowledgement_SelectedNotifications() throws Exception {
        // Mock OperatorSubscriber
        OperatorSubscriber os = mock(OperatorSubscriber.class);
        when(session.getAttribute("operator")).thenReturn(os);
    
        // Mock NotificationMessage
        NotificationMessage message = new NotificationMessage();
        message.setBtnClicked("Acknowledge Selected Notifications");
        message.setSelectedMessages(new String[]{"1", "2"});
    
        // Call the service method
        String result = service.acknowledgement(request, response, message);
    
        // Verify
        assertEquals("redirect:/viewNotifications.do", result);
        verify(delegate, times(2)).acknowledgeNotification(eq(os), any(Long.class));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(delegate);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testAcknowledgement_AllNotifications() throws Exception {
        // Mock OperatorSubscriber
        OperatorSubscriber os = mock(OperatorSubscriber.class);
        when(session.getAttribute("operator")).thenReturn(os);
    
        // Mock NotificationMessage
        NotificationMessage message = new NotificationMessage();
        message.setBtnClicked("Acknowledge All Notifications");
        message.setNotificationIds(new String[]{"10", "15"});
    
        // Mock getMaxnotificationid method
        when(service.getMaxnotificationid(message.getNotificationIds())).thenReturn(15L);
    
        // Call the service method
        String result = service.acknowledgement(request, response, message);
    
        // Verify
        assertEquals("redirect:/viewNotifications.do", result);
        verify(delegate).acknowledgeAllNotifications(eq(os), eq(15L));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(delegate);
    }

}
```

---

But on this line

```
when(service.getMaxnotificationid(message.getNotificationIds())).thenReturn(15L);
```

the test is failing saying that getNotificationIds() cannot return Long it should return String[]

THIS getNotificationsIds() method is the getter method which is returning String[] and in parameter it is taking Sting[] only.

like this :

```
public String getNotificationIds(){ return notificationIds: }
```

the variable is this:
private String[] notificationIds.

Sorry In advance if it is a silly problem I am very new to unit test. And thank you so much If you can help me in this.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why are you stubbing your real service? You can only stub mocks and `service` isn't a mock. And if you are stubbing your service under test, then what are you testing? Correct, nothing.

Comment: Also, please fix the formatting of your post. Fix your compiler errors. Properly indent your code. Don't make it hard for others to help you.

Comment: But the problem is you are calling `when(…).thenReturn(…)` with something that's not a mock. So this is not going to work, because there are no calls on a mock object that Mockito could record and then stub out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.